# Matlab 1D wave equation FDM second order in time, fourth order in space

Tags: matlab

I wrote a function to solve the 1D wave equation with FDM. Therefore i used second order accuracy in time and fourth order in space and an explicit FD scheme. 
I already implemented the solver function in Matlab with an matrix-vector-multiplication approach (alternative this can be done iterative) with periodic boundary conditions.

To verify the code i used the Method of Manufactured Solution. My approach is to assume the solution as

```
p(t,x)=sin(x+t)+sin(x-t)
```

which is periodic and sufficient smooth and differentiable. I implemented a source term f which is as well as the initial data input for the following function

```
function [x,t,P_End]= MMS(f,I,G,L,v,T,J,CFL,x)

% Initialisation

deltax=x(2)-x(1);
deltat=CFL*deltax/abs(v);
c=(v*deltat/deltax)^2;


t=(0:deltat:T);
N=length(t);

A=zeros(J,J);

for k=1:J

% periodic boundary condition
  if k==1 
     A(1,1)=-c*5/2;
     A(1,2)=c*4/3;
     A(1,3)=c/12;
     A(1,J-1)=c/12;
     A(1,J)=c*4/3;

   elseif k==J
      A(J,1)=c*4/3;
      A(J,2)=c/12;
      A(J,J-2)=c/12;
      A(J,J-1)=c*4/3;
      A(J,J)=-c*5/2;

 elseif k==2
      A(2,J)=c/12;
      A(2,1)=c*4/3;
      A(2,2)=-c*5/2;
      A(2,3)=c*4/3;
      A(2,4)=c/12; 

 elseif k==J-1
       A(J-1,1)=c*1/12;
       A(J-1,J-1)=-c*5/2;
       A(J-1,J)=c*4/3;
       A(J-1,J-2)=c*4/3;
       A(J-1,J-3)=c*1/12;

   else
        A(k,k-2)=c/12;
        A(k,k-1)=c*4/3;
        A(k,k)=-c*5/2;
        A(k,k+1)=c*4/3;
        A(k,k+2)=c/12;
   end
 end

    %Allocate memory
    P_0=zeros(J,1);
    b=zeros(J,1);
    H=zeros(J,1);

    %Initial data read in
    for i=1:J
        P_0(i)=I(x(i));
        b(i)=f(x(i),t(1));
        H(i)=G(x(i));
    end

    %Calculation of first time step separate because to time steps back 
    %are needed in the iteration
    P_1=0.5*A*P_0+(deltat^2/2)*b+2*deltat*H+P_0;

    P_n_minus_1=P_0;
    P_n=P_1;
    P_End=zeros(N,J); % Solution matrix
    P_End(1,:)=P_0;
    P_End(2,:)=P_1;

    for n=2:N
        for i=1:J
            b(i)=f(x(i),t(n));
        end

        %Iterative calculation for t_2,...,t_N
        P_n_plus_1=A*P_n+(deltat^2)*b-P_n_minus_1+2*P_n;

        %Overwriting
        P_n_minus_1=P_n;
        P_n=P_n_plus_1;

        P_End(n,:)=P_n_plus_1;
    end

    end
```

The function call is then

```
clear all; clc; close all;

%% Initialisierung

    % Grid points in space x_0,...x_L
    x = -2 : 0.01 : 2;
    J = length(x);

    xDelta = x(2) - x(1);
    T = 2;
    v = 0.5; %velocity constant
    CFL = 0.5; %Courant Friedrich Lewis number

    %Source term right-hand side of the wave equation
    f = @(x,t) abs(v^2-1)*(sin(x+t)+sin(x-t));

    %Initial data for the estimated sound pressure function p(t,x), t=0
    I = @(x)  2*sin(x);

    % \partial p/ \partial t , t=0
    G = @(x) 0;

   [x,t,P_End]= MMS(f,I,G,v,T,J,CFL,x);
```

This initial data and source term input leads to a solution that proceed like the assumed solution but in range ob `+/- 10^24.
What an i doing wrong here? I already reviewed the code hundred of times but could not detect any code mistakes.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: You don't seem to get any propagation of the waves, they just cause some form of constructive interference.
plotting them using this gives you a nice idea of the time history:
`for ii=1:length(t), plot(x,P_End(ii,:)), title(num2str(t(ii))),pause(0.05),end`

Comment: You are absolutely right. There was a big mistake in the finite difference scheme. Instead of `c/12` it has to be `-c/12`. Thanks a lot!